# Is this a proper wet vent?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I have mocked up a bathroom remodel waste line. It is the white pvc in the image. The toilet is 93" away from the stack and is the most downstream fixture. I think I did everything right but I'm still not sure that I don't need to include another vent. Would someone kindly give me a second opinion?
[image: Wet vent mockup]

Comment: You have HVAC in the cavities where you plan to run drains.  Will that clear?  Is that permitted under code?

Comment: The closest ventilation is ceiling fan for the bathroom below and it's being moved over to the next cavity where it will have more clearance. I really don't know what code says about the proximity though.

Comment: What code is this? IPC or UPC?

Comment: By "another vent," do you mean in addition to the stack?

Comment: what is the black pipe with the rag in it?  are you dry venting your sink on the left?  What sizes and distances are the toilet and shower from the stack?

Answer (score 1):

In most plumbing codes that I'm familiar with this is not the correct arrangement.

The toilet should be the last fixture connected in a wet vent or be connected via a symmetrical fitting (so that the flow from the toilet drain does not flow past the drain connection of the other fixtures).

The simplest solution for this setup would be to replace the two wyes with a single 3 x 2 double wye. Also replace the 90° at the sink with a tee and continue the vent.

Comment: Yes. Flushing the toilet could siphon your vanity and shower traps.

Comment: Under IPC, the last fixture thing is only for vertical wet vents. See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-9-vents#IPC2021P1_Ch09_Sec912.1 versus the vertical wet vent spec that immediately follows.

Comment: Under IPC, you're allowed one fixture drain upstream of the dry vented tributary. See https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2021P1/chapter-9-vents#IPC2021P1_Ch09_Sec912.2.1. Dry venting at the OP's lav is sufficient assuming that everything is sized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe toilet has to be no further than 6 ft from vent (stack in this case).  You can simply add a vent to the sink and then your sink becomes a wet vent.  Then you just need to ensure your wet vent (the sink) hits the 3 inch within 6 feet of the toilet.  Also, I think a wet vent has to be 2 inch pipe.  Your sink looks like 1.5 inch.

Comment: Can you point to where in the code (IRC, IPC, UPC) that this is specified?

Answer (score 0):

Under the International Plumbing Code, a sanitary tee venting upward at the sink connection makes this a conformant horizontal wet vented system. That's assuming that everything is sized correctly and your lengths are within spec.

Under the Uniform Plumbing Code, your toilet is the most *upstream* fixture, not the most *downstream* fixture, making your installation non-conformant.